# Font won't load even though described properly

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a font locally stored in resources/fonts/ and am properly referring to it, but it somehow won't load. My `<style>` in html:

```
<style>
    @font-face{
        font-family:"franklin_gothic_condensed";
        src:url("resources/fonts/fgc.ttf");
    }
</style>
```

The html where I am using the font:

```
<p id="missieHead1" class="headText">
    Missie 2014.<br>
    Onze terugkeer.
</p>
```

The CSS where I apply the font:

```
.headText{
    font-family:"franklin_gothic_condensed";
    color:white;
}
```

I acquired the fonts through our supplier, who happens to be a globally known German holding company with investments in the automotive industry. I made sure that my URLs were correct because I tried it with other fonts in the same directory, and they all worked. As for how they were created, I have no idea and I do not believe I am at a position to request how they were created.

I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong here, because I'm at my wits' end. Looking at other questions didn't help me either.

SOLUTION: I found out that our supplier supplied us with a faulty font. Searching the font on the web and downloading it worked.

Comment: Try add `format('ttf')` to your `src` line and be sure that path is relative to your css file

Comment: Try `src: url("resources/fonts/fgc____.ttf")` !

Comment: @codename- Where exactly do I put `format('ttf')`? in the `src` line? Do I put it behind `("resources/fonts/fgc_____.ttf")`?

Comment: @abtrout That sadly didn't work.

Comment: @TobyvanKempen add `format('ttf')` after end of url close bracket and before semicolon -> `src : url('...') format('ttf');`

Comment: You should edit the question so that the code is correct, as suggested in comments and answers, and specify where the font was got from, how the font files were created, and how you made sure that all the URLs of the font files actually work.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect on the points given here.

Comment: @codename- adding `format("ttf")` to `src:url("resources/fonts/fgc.ttf")` didn't cut it. I tried it with a font that did work, and it even kind of "broke" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing this as an answer since the comments above are cramped for explanation.

First, as mentioned above, the source declaration is slightly wrong:

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"franklin_gothic_condensed";
  src: url("resources/fonts/fgc_____.ttf");
}
```

Second, you should wrap your `font-family` in quotes. The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop) lays down a few guidelines about quoting font families that contain punctation. While there are situations where you can get away with not using quotes, it's generally a good idea to use them:

```
.headText{
  font-family: "franklin_gothic_condensed";
  color: white;
}
```

Otherwise, make sure that your .ttf is being loaded. Try renaming it.

Comment: Tried all of it, and renamed the font to `fgc.ttf` for convenience, but it still won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Toby, not sure. I tried it locally (copied Andale Mono from my fontbook to andalemono.ttf) and used this HTML file: 

http://pastebin.com/T6zr8VhD

Worked fine =\. Did you include a doctype at the front of your file?

Comment: I noticed that the font I had received would not load, as I tried it with a different font, after which it loaded perfectly. Regardless, I chose your answer because if I didn't know the things that you have shown in your answer, I still wouldn't have an idea of the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your server type, but if you are using a windows server and IIS you might want to verify that the ttf mimetype has been set up properly.

Here are the mimetypes for web fonts in IIS:

```
.eot   application/vnd.ms-fontobject  
.ttf   application/octet-stream  
.svg   image/svg+xml  
.woff  application/x-woff
```

Comment: Woah now, I have no idea what all that means. I merely want to implement my font into my HTML.

Comment: Ah sorry, if you're web server is windows based and uses IIS (internet information services) rather then linux you need to tell the server how to handle the font files or they won't load.

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Webkit browsers on the mac OS can't load font files with certain unicode characters in the name. Honestly I'm not 100% sure but it could be the underscore (_) characters in the name. This article talks about the gotchas with file names on Mac OS. http://www.paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley

Comment: Removed all the underscores from both the font-family name and the file itself, but it didn't cut it. However, that's no matter. I found out that the one who supplied us with the font supplied us with a faulty one, and has been replaced accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for declaring the source of the file is:

```
src: url('url of the file');
```

So, do this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"franklin_gothic_condensed";
    src:url("resources/fonts/fgc_____.ttf");
}
```

Comment: Changing `src:url:"resources/fonts/fgc_____.ttf";` to `src:url("resources/fonts/fgc_____.ttf");` sadly didn't work. Any ideas?